# CKEditor Grey Area Issue

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor 4 with BootstrapCK4. I am using it in my ASP.NET MVC Project.When I open the the page wit CKEditor , I see only a big grey blank instead of normal display of editor. It's like that:

[image]

HTML output of my codes:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>YaziEkle</title>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
       @import "/Content/admin.css"
    </style>

    <script src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="kapsayici">
        <div class="wrapper">
<ul class="menu">
<li class="anasayfa-m"><a href="">Anasayfa</a></li>
<li class="yazilar-m"><a href="">Yazılar</a></li>
<li class="kategoriler-m"><a href="">Kategoriler</a></li>
<li class="sayfalar-m"><a href="">Sayfalar</a></li>
<li class="gorunum-m"><a href="">Görünüm</a></li>
<li class="yorumlar-m"><a href="">Yorumlar</a></li>
<li class="kullanicilar-m"><a href="">Kullanıcılar</a></li>
</ul><br />
</div>

<form id="form">

    <select data-val="true" data-val-required="Kategori seçilmelidir." id="Kategori" name="Kategori"><option value="1">kk</option>
<option value="2">kk</option>
<option value="3">kk</option>
</select>
     <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-maxlength="Baslik alanı, uzunluğu en fazla &#39;-1&#39; olan bir dize veya dizi türü olmalıdır." data-val-maxlength-max="-1" data-val-required="Başlık boş bırakılamaz." id="Baslik" name="Baslik" placeholder="Başlık" type="text" value="" />  
    <label class="control-label" for="inputError"><span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Baslik" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></label>
     <textarea cols="20" data-val="true" data-val-maxlength="Icerik alanı, uzunluğu en fazla &#39;-1&#39; olan bir dize veya dizi türü olmalıdır." data-val-maxlength-max="-1" data-val-required="İçerik boş bırakılamaz" id="yaziekle" name="Icerik" rows="2">
</textarea> 
    <label class="control-label" for="inputError"><span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Icerik" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></label>
</form>
    <script>
            CKEDITOR.replace("yaziekle",
                {
                    width: "61.5%",
                }
                );
    </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Swr9K/1/

What's the reason of this problem? How can I solve? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Removing the width attribute will get the ckEditor panel showing.

Comment: Yes, it got the CKEditor panel showing but next to the grey area. I think the grey blank is not a CKEditor problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing jQuery adapter for CKEditor. Like this:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

you should find this js file in your CKEditor installation folder.

Comment: Its not jQuery library. Its native CKEditor adapter for jQuery. Take a look: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_jquery

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't change anything.